# Pass a WebGrid to Controller

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, controller, webgrid

I want to send the whole WebGrid to my controller and convert it into a DataTable.

```
var grid1 = new WebGrid(Model.dsvm as IEnumerable<ASP_Upload_Version_1.Models.Share_Template>, canPage: true, canSort: false);
@grid1.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table table-sm table-striped table-condensed",
htmlAttributes: new { @id = "GridPractice", @class = "table table-sm table-striped-left table-bordered table-condensed", @style = "width:100%" },
columns: grid1.Columns(
    grid1.Column("PracticeArea", "Practice Area"),
    grid1.Column("MarketArea", "Market Area"),
    grid1.Column(format: @<text>
    <a data-title="Are you sure to deactivate this Input?" class="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash" style="color:red"></i></a></text>, header: "Remove")));
```

So, that I can send the datatable as a User defined type Parameter to a SQL Procedure.

Is converting the WebGrid into a JSON result a good approach?
are there any easier alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I converted the Grid into json using

```
var _griddata = gridTojson("GridPractice");
```

and passed it to the controller. Over there I converted it into a dictionary using

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> log = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string[]>>(GridData);
```

Then I moved the data into a DataTable with the following code

```
DataTable PracticeTable= new DataTable();

PracticeTable.Columns.Add("TestColumn1");
PracticeTable.Columns.Add("");

for (int i = 0; i < log.Count; i++)
{
    PracticeTable.Rows.Add(log["" + i + ""][0], log["" + i + ""][1]);
}
```